# copied mysql table doesn't allow to edit

Tags: mysql

I created (copied) a table through mysql. "CREATE TABLE bal0321 AS SELECT * FROM balance". But the new table doesn't allow to edit records. Why ?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to edit a row?

Comment: In MySql workbench, it simply doesn't allow to change contents in rows.

Comment: After juggling I found the answer Myself.  CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT FROM old_table doesn't add a primary key. It has to be two step SQL;  CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;       Joe.